# Binding "BindingList" to DataTemplate with converter does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, bindinglist

I have view model `BindingList<Wave>`.

here is the model (only one property is shown).

```
public class Wave : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _period;

    public double Period
    {
        get { return _period; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_period)) return;
            _period = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Period));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Below Im trying to bind view model into canvas and draw them with polyline which works but only once.

The problem is that when i change the properties the view does not update. (the converter does not fire after first time).

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WaveCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Polyline Points="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PlotterConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`PlotterConverter` just returns `PointCollection`. with some formula but its not important here.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new PointCollection(GetPoints(value as Wave));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `Binding Mode = TwoWay`.

```
<Polyline Points="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource PlotterConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: thanks but it is still not updating. the converter fires only for first time. either i use one way or two way binding mode.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary If you remove the converter, can you see the values changing ?

Comment: the converter converts `Wave` into `PointCollection`. thats impossible because Points property needs PointCollection. `Wave` just holds the formula to generate the points. the formula is dynamic. let me try to put PointCollection inside Wave model.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Replace your PolyLine control in DataTemplate with <TextBlock Text="{Binding .Count, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

Comment: the Wave does not have Count property. how ever i fixed it by putting point collection as a property in Wave, and then bind to that property. it is not related to binding mode because it also works with one way. current binding is now `<Polyline Points="{Binding Points"/>`. the Points is now a new property inside Wave which returns point collection. the idea you give me to remove the converter was the answer! ;)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Also please replace BindingList<T> with ObservableCollection<T>, and tell what happens.

Comment: i did. no changes. it worked like bindinglist @AnjumSKhan